# Slide a div from left-right or right left with preserving div size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a slide effect on a div from left to right or from right to left as in

```
$('#div').show('slide', {direction:'left'}, 1000);
```

being my html is

```
<div id="div-pre">
</div>
<div id="div">
</div>
<div id="div-nex">
</div
```

But the problem with this approach is that we are hiding the #div initially by setting

```
#div{
display:none;
}
```

so that we cannot preserve the width of #div

I have came across another method by making the visibility: hidden as in

```
$("div").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

to preserve the width of the div
but this method does not give the sliding effect from left to right or right to left

> So I want to achieve both "the effect as in .show('slide', [option], [speed]) altogether with
>   preserving the div width"

Comment: Use CSS @keyframes rule

Comment: Please post some more of your code in the question (i.e. the div's and your whole javascript code)

Comment: @LaurensSwart i added a bit of html to make more sense

Comment: Ah I see, I already added an answer below. Hope you can use my example to apply this knowledge to your own case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no example code to go off, I decided to write a basic example of how you could approach this. Basically, you put an `overflow: hidden` container around the thing that you want to slide to the left while preserving width, and you then animate a movement leftwards using `animate('left':'-pixels');`. Your div has to be positioned relatively for this to work. See example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slideLeft').click(function(){
   $('.slider').animate(
     {'left':'-600px'},
      1000,
      function(){
        $('.slider').hide();
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.slider{
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideLeft{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    Hi, I have some content!
  </div>
</div>
<button class="slideLeft">Slide me left!</button>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I used your code alone. It did not work in my file I doubt which is because there are some wrongly-assigned/incompatible parent div properties. I will sort it out, and thanks for showing the right way to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your div in another div with overflow:hidden and than you move to right or left the div inside.